# How to ignore values that are not repeated in Python Counter

Tags: python

I need to make sure that the answer in the first case does not output the value of the count_value.

````py
from collections import Counter

def duplicate_count(text):
    count, value, count_value = len(set([i for i in (list(text.lower())) if (list(text.lower())).count(i) >= 2])),set([i for i in (list(text.lower())) if (list(text.lower())).count(i) >= 2]), Counter(text.lower()).most_common(2)
    return f'->{count} # {" and ".join(x for x in list(value))} повторилось {count_value[0][1]} раз'

print(duplicate_count('abcde'))
print(duplicate_count('aabbcde'))
print(duplicate_count('indivisibility')) ```

>>> ->0 #  повторилось 1 раз
>>> ->2 # a and b повторилось 2 раз
>>> ->1 # i повторилось 6 раз
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It isn't clear what your question is.   What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
def duplicate_count(text):
    tlower = text.lower()
    count = set([(i, tlower.count(i)) for i in tlower if tlower.count(i) >= 2])
    chars = ' and '.join([i[0] for i in count])
    if count:
        return f'->{len(count)} # {chars} повторилось {max(i[1] for i in count)} раз'
    else:
        return f'->{len(count)}'

print(duplicate_count('abcde'))
print(duplicate_count('aabbcde'))
print(duplicate_count('indivisibility'))

->0
->2 # a and b повторилось 2 раз
->1 # i повторилось 6 раз
```